# Symfony DiscriminatorColumn - one entity with multiple entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, discriminator

I have 3 tables, Articles, ArticlesTree, fieldsi18n...
my current code has OnoToOne relationship between fieldsi18n and the other 2 entities.
So my fieldsi18n's table has one column to the articles_id and other for the tree_id... how can I accomplish this with just one column that will be named to element_id
How can i use the DiscriminatorColumn ?

HexFieldI18n:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\HexFieldI18nRepository")
 */
class HexFieldI18n
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\HexArticlesTree", mappedBy="label", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $tree;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\HexArticles", mappedBy="label", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\HexArticles", mappedBy="label", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $article;
}
```

HexArticles

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\HexArticlesRepository")
 */
class HexArticles
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\HexFieldI18n", inversedBy="article", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $label;
}
```

HexArticlesTree

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\HexArticlesTreeRepository")
 */
class HexArticlesTree
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\HexFieldI18n", inversedBy="article", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $label;
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look about Doctrine JointTable : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_jointable

Answer (score 0):

I don't undertand **just one column that will be named to element_id**. Doctrine has several annotations like `@InheritanceType` to determinate the inheranceType `SINGLE_TABLE` or `JOINED`. I only have used `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance that basicly has columns to determinate its entity, which are saved in the column that you mark with `@DiscrimatorType` annotation, you must remember that entities will not be persisting to the database, only acts like a descriminator.